# Parameter set but not used

Tags: c++

I have two classes "IDASectionA" and "XIDA_A" and two structs "s_Color" and "s_GetColor".

s_Color, s_GetColor:

```
struct s_Color{
 std::string Name;
 XColor X_Color;
};
struct s_GetColor{
 s_Color BackColor, BorderColor[3], BorderColorA, ForeColor, ForeColorA;
 s_Color Min[3], Max[3], Close[3];
 XColor Transparent;
};
```

XIDA_A:

```
XIDA_A{
 ...
 s_GetColor s_Section, s_Header, s_StatBox;
 int GetXColors(s_GetColor *vSec, s_GetColor *vHead, s_GetColor *vStatBox);
};

int XIDA_A::GetXColors(s_GetColor *vSec, s_GetColor *vHead, s_GetColor *vStatBox){  //  <- HERE "Set but not used
...
vSec = &this->s_Section;
vHead = &this->s_Header;
vStatBox = &this->s_StatBox;
}
```

IDASectionA:

```
class IDASectionA{
 ...
 s_GetColor *mCrSec, *mCrHead, *mCrStatBox;
};

IDASectionA::IDASectionA(){
 mXIDA_A->GetXColors(this->mCrSec, this->mCrHead, this->mCrStatBox);
}
```

Why isn't vSec, vHead, vStatBox set but not used?
BTW the code is also not working properly. Values are various...
Using a returned vector is matching properly.

Best regards
Earlybite

Comment: You probably want this `int XIDA_A::GetXColors(s_GetColor *&vSec, s_GetColor *&vHead, s_GetColor *&vStatBox)`

Comment: `void foo(int bar)
{
  bar = 2;
}

void test()
{
  int bar = 123;
  foo(bar);
}`: what's the value of bar after the call to `foo`?

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the address of *function local pointers*

```
int XIDA_A::GetXColors(s_GetColor *vSec, s_GetColor *vHead, s_GetColor *vStatBox)
```

To have these pointers modified outside the function too, pass them by reference

```
int XIDA_A::GetXColors(s_GetColor*& vSec, s_GetColor*& vHead, s_GetColor*& vStatBox)
```

Comment: I havn't tested it yet, but this (*&) is practicable, too? Hadn't known this, thanks.